# "not exists" or "exists" query with pagination taking too much time to executing in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I am try to fetch record using "not exists" and "exists" command.

its working fine with findAll .. but with pagination "MAX_JOIN_SIZE" issue rise

Code :

```
$this->User->unbindModelAll();
$this->Booking->unbindModelAll();
$this->User->bindModel(array('hasMany' => array('UserImage'), 'hasOne' =>array('Booking','RentalGoal', 'Verification', 'AbcCheck')), false);

$cond_user = array(
                'User.id NOT' => $a,
                'User.is_hide' =>1, 'User.status' =>1, 
                'RentalGoal.looking_for' =>1,'RentalGoal.room_type <>' => null, 'RentalGoal.step1_completed' =>1, 'Verification.rent_gaol' => 1,
                'OR'=>array(
                array('not exists ' . '(select id from dev_bookings ' . 'where dev_bookings.user_id = ' . 'User.id AND dev_bookings.move_in =1 AND dev_bookings.move_out = 0 AND dev_bookings.rent_term = "m")'),
                array('exists ' . '(select id from dev_user_images ' . 'where dev_user_images.user_id = ' . 'User.id AND dev_user_images.status =1 AND dev_user_images.default = 1)'),
                false),);
```

Working fine with >>

```
    $new_arr = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => $cond_user,
        'limit' =>400, 'recursive' => 2, 
       'order' => array('User.user_verification DESC'),
        ));
```

but not working with paginate

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => $cond_user,
        'limit' =>100, 
        'recursive' =>2, 
       'order' => array('User.user_verification DESC'),
       );
$new_arr = $this->paginate('User');
```

Error >

```
2014-07-04 14:38:51 Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1104 The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay
```

AppModel >

```
class AppModel extends Model {


function beforeFind($query)   
{
    $this->query('SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1');
}
```

}

what was the wrong with it? i also use ,false into bind model.

please help

thanks

Answer (score 1):

MySQL determines whether or not a query is a 'big select' based on the value of 'max_join_size'. If the query is likely to have to examine more than this number of rows, it will consider it a 'big select'. Use 'show variables' to view the value of the max join size.

I believe that indexing and particular a good where clause will prevent this problem from occuring.

SQL_BIG_SELECTS is used to prevent users from accidentally executing excessively large queries. It is okay to set it to ON in mysql.cnf or using the command-line option at startup.

You can set SQL_BIG_SELECTS in my.cnf or at server startup. It can also be set on a session basis with 'SET SESSION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1'.

Not that I can think of. I would just check your query to make sure that you really need to use it. Our servers have it turned on by default, and max_join_size is very large.

set max join size 
SET GLOBAL max_join_size=1844674407370955148795;

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html